# How to restore oracle db script,when using partition by then standard version can use

Tags: database, oracle

**It's sample Script from db using partition by key word**

```
create table ANDY.TEST
(
  create_year    VARCHAR2(4) not null,    
  no      VARCHAR2(10) not null,
  id       VARCHAR2(10) not null,
  update_id        VARCHAR2(10) not null,
  update_date      DATE not null
)
partition by range (CREATE_YEAR)
(
  partition TEST_2021 values less than ('2022')
    tablespace TEST_DATA_01
    pctfree 10
    initrans 1
    maxtrans 255
    storage
    (
      initial 1M
      next 1M
      minextents 1
      maxextents unlimited
    ),
  partition TEST_2022 values less than ('2023')
    tablespace TEST_DATA_02
    pctfree 10
    initrans 1
    maxtrans 255
    storage
    (
      initial 1M
      minextents 1
      maxextents unlimited
    )
);
alter table ANDY.TEST
  add constraint TEST_PK primary key (CREATE_YEAR, NO, ID)
  using index 
  local;
alter index ANDY.TEST_PK nologging;
```

**Is problem come, Dose any idea can let script changing to standard version can use? and have same result**

**I only can run create,other script will fail to run**

```
create table ANDY.TEST
(
  create_year    VARCHAR2(4) not null,    
  no      VARCHAR2(10) not null,
  id       VARCHAR2(10) not null,
  update_id        VARCHAR2(10) not null,
  update_date      DATE not null
)
```

Comment: _"Dose any idea can let script changing to standard version can use?"_   I really don't know what you are trying to ask here, but it _sounds to me_ like you are asking if you can use partitioning in Oracle Standard Edition.  If that is your question, the answer is no, SE does not support partitioning.  If I have mis-understood your question, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

We can't have two tables (indeed any objects) of the same name in the same schema. So it really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

The obvious option is to drop the one table before running the alternate script.

Another approach would be to name the tables differently. But presumably you want to run the same code against both variants. That is where synonyms become useful.

First script:

```
create table ANDY.TEST_PARTITIONED ...
```

Second script:

```
create table ANDY.TEST_STANDARD ...
```

To allow code to reference the partitioned table use this synonym:

```
create or replace synonym andy.test for andy.test_partitioned;
```

To allow code to reference the unpartitioned table use this synonym:

```
create or replace synonym andy.test for andy.test_standard;
```

---

If this answer has not resolved your issue please **edit your question** to provide more details regarding what you are trying to achieve.